# Toggle image on click lua

Tags: image, lua, toggle, autoplay-media-studio

I'm trying to toggle an image when a user clicks on the image. It is meant to change the image and mute the audio that is playing in background and vice versa. I'm using lua in a program called Indigo Autoplay media studio 8.

here is the code:

```
if (Audio.Play(CHANNEL_BACKGROUND) == true) then
    Audio.Pause(CHANNEL_BACKGROUND);
    Image.Load("playpause", "AutoPlay\\Images\\gg57570759.png");
else
    Image.Load("playpause", "AutoPlay\\Images\\gg57570759 on.png");
    Audio.Play(CHANNEL_BACKGROUND);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following script to `On Click` event of the image:

```
Audio.TogglePlay(CHANNEL_BACKGROUND);
```

Then open the page properties and add the following script to `On Audio` event of the page:

```
if (e_State == "Pause") then
    Image.Load("playpause", "AutoPlay\\Images\\gg57570759.png");
else
    Image.Load("playpause", "AutoPlay\\Images\\gg57570759 on.png");
end
```